# Find the smallest 2-colored complete graph that contains either one of specific subgraphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

Determine the smallest $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, if we have a complete graph $K_N$​ with edges colored in two colors (let's say red and blue), it will always contain either a red $K_3$​ or a blue $K_{1,3}$​.

I attempted something like this: let's consider $K_6$​. We know that in every $K_6$​, there's at least one monochromatic triangle. If this triangle is red, we are done. And for "if not, ..." I believe I can use a proof by contradiction to demonstrate that it's impossible for this $K_6$​ not to have a blue $K_{1,3}$​. However, I wasn't able to complete this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$N=6$ is too small, because the graph $K_{3,3}$ contains no $K_3$ and its complement contains no $K_{1,3}$. I will show that a red/blue coloring of $K_7$ contains either a red $K_3$ or else a blue $K_{1,3}$.

Consider a vertex $x$. If $x$ is joined to three vertices by blue edges, there is your blue $K_{1,3}$. Otherwise, $x$ is joined to four vertices by red edges. If two of those four vertices are joined by a red edge, we have a red $K_3$; otherwise we have a blue $K_4$ which contains a blue $K_{1,3}$.

**More generally,** given graphs $G$ and $H$, let $R(G,H)$ denote the smallest number $N$ such that every red/blue coloring of the edges of $K_N$ contains either a red copy of $G$ or else a blue copy of $H$. We have shown that $R(K_3,K_{1,3})=7$. In the same way you can show that $R(K_3,K_{1,t})=2t+1$, or more generally (by induction on $s$) that $R(K_s,K_{1,t})=(s-1)t+1$.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments (letting the red edges form a $K_{3,3}$), $n = 6$ won't work. We show that $n = 7$ is the smallest integer that works, and that every red/blue coloring of $K_7$ has a red triangle or a blue $K_{1,3}$.

Let $n = 7$.

Say the graph does not have a blue $K_{1,3}$. This means for every $v \in G$, $\deg_{G,red}(v) \geq (n-1) - 2 = 4$. Then $e_{red}(G)  \geq 7 \cdot 4 / 2 = 14$. Mantel's theorem tells us that the maximum number of edges a triangle free graph can have for $n=7$ is $3 \cdot  4 = 12$. So $G$ has a red triangle, as desired.